# UIDatePicker shows incorrect minuteInterval until refreshed

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've got a UITableViewCell with a UIDatePicker in the contentView. I have set the minuteInterval in the nib to 30, and I do so programatically as well. However, when the tableview cell is first displayed, the date picker does not respect my minuteInterval! The next time it is displayed, it has corrected itself. I've tried setNeedsDisplay but that doesnt seem to work...

How can i force a UIDatePicker to 'refresh' itself?

Here is my code:

```
DDDatePickerTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:DatePickerCellIdentifier
                                                                  forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([self.expandedIndexPath isEqual:self.startTimeIndexPath]) {
        cell.datePicker.date = self.selectedStartDate;
        cell.datePicker.minimumDate = self.minDate;
        cell.datePicker.maximumDate = self.selectedEndDate;
    } else if ([self.expandedIndexPath isEqual:self.endTimeIndexPath]) {
        cell.datePicker.date = self.selectedEndDate;
        cell.datePicker.minimumDate = self.selectedStartDate;
        cell.datePicker.maximumDate = self.maxDate;
    }

    cell.datePicker.calendar = self.calendar;
    cell.datePicker.minuteInterval = 30.f;
    cell.datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears as though `datePickerMode` must be set before `minuteInterval`